# path variable is not being set properly

Tags: java, ant, path, cmd

I have installed ant-1.9.2 and jdk1.7.0 in windows 7 and tried the following ways to set the path

```
C:\>set ANT_HOME=C:\Users\sahaya_s\Downloads\apache-ant-1.9.2;

C:\>set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45;

C:\>set path=%ANT_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;

C:\>echo %path%
C:\Users\anto\Downloads\apache-ant-1.9.2;\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45;\bin;
```

here the path has divided into two. what is went wrong?

and tried by giving complete path

```
C:\>set path=C:\Users\sahaya_s\Downloads\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;

C:\>echo %path%
C:\Users\sahaya_s\Downloads\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;

C:\>java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\>ant -version
ANT_HOME is set incorrectly or ant could not be located. Please set ANT_HOME.
```

Still am getting problem with ANT_HOME. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have unneeded `;` causing your path to split. Use:

```
C:\>set ANT_HOME=C:\Users\sahaya_s\Downloads\apache-ant-1.9.2
```